# Scrolling in Terminal when program is opened in MacOS Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

After I upgraded to Sierra from Mavericks I noticed that when I open something in Terminal with for example `less` or `vi` and I want to scroll back to see previous lines the scrolling happens inside the programs. How can I change it back to 'just scroll'?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens in El Captain as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can scroll the screen while holding <kbd>fn</kbd> or <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> key.

You can disable this completely by unticking:

**Terminal Preferences** → **Profiles** → **Keyboard** → **Scroll Alternate Screen**.

[image: profiles screenshot]